# Inheriting from a template class which has the derived class as a parameter

Tags: c++, templates

While reading the source code of the [vcglib](https://github.com/cnr-isti-vclab/vcglib), I encountered some template code like the following:

```
class MyVertex: public VertexSimp2<MyVertex, MyEdge, MyFace, vcg::Coord3f>{};
class MyFace: public Face<MyVertex, MyEdge, MyFace, face::VertexRef>{};
```

My question is: the class MyVertex inherits from a template class which has type MyVertex as a parameter, and MyFace inherits from a template class which has  MyFace as a parameter. It seems to me that at the time of definition of the derived class, the base class is not well-defined. How should I decipher this piece of code?

Comment: This is known as [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), a fairly common pattern